# Induction and Countable Set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Ok well everytime ive seen induction being used, its been on the naturals for a statement we wish to prove. My question is would any countable set also work? Hence, doing induction on the rationals as they are countable. If this is possible, could someone please give some examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, yes. In practice, no.

Note that induction makes use of the fact that that we have a specific natural number $1$ to start from and a *successor* function ("add $1$") that allows us to reach any natural number by starting at $1$ and repeatedly applying the successor function.
There is no (natural) such successor function for the rationals.
Of cours in principle we can make use of some enumeration $q_1, q_2, q_3, \ldots$ of the rationals - but then how would you prove that "If the statement holds for $q_n$ then it also holds for $q_{n+1}$" if there is no natural relation between $q_n$ and $q_{n+1}$?

Comment: ok I see the problem you raised and its clear the naturals is perfect for induction with the whole peano axoms etc., but is there any other set which is countable and which induction can be used on (ignoring the rationals). If not, ill end my case but I seem to remember a long time ago a person claimed to have done induction on a set which wasnt the naturals.

Comment: @WhizKid: some possible sets where the successor function could be better defined are the odds, the primes, etc.  But using one of these sets is not different enough from using the natural numbers and simply applying a function that translates to one of the sets.  In fact, each of them is still indexed in terms of the naturals, e.g., $p_i$ is the $i$th prime...

Comment: @WhizKid Induction (in a just slightly different formulation than what you are accustomed to) works for all *wellordered* sets, for example for *ordinal numbers*, of which the set of natural numbers with standard order is just the smallest infinite example. In fact, these may even be uncountable!

Comment: thanks! i see the picture :)